# What is the first use of the word "Seder" (סדר) for the Pesach night proceedings?

Tags: words, passover-seder-hagada, provenance

The Pesach night proceedings are commonly called the "Seder" (סדר). This word more generally means "order."

What is the first recorded use of the word סדר for this event?

Answer (score 4):

The earliest source I know of is the Siddur of Rav Amram Gaon. He lived in the 9th century.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43020&st=&pgnum=82&hilite=

Comment: His book is called Seder Amram Gaon. I bet Seder for him is the same way we use Siddur.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. I was going to write it that way, but I've noticed most people refer to it as Siddur.

Comment: My point is his calling the Pesach night liturgy "Seder" is probably not unique to Pesach

Comment: I disagree. If you look at other halachos in the book such as Purim or Chanukah, they are not referred to in body of text as 'Seder'. The titles for the various sections use the word 'seder' but the were added by the printer, they are not in the original. This can be verified by looking at other editions of Seder Rav Amram Gaon.